# Passing array of values in Sinatra GET in a less verbose way

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I know Sinatra is not super concise when it comes to this topic. To pass an array of values to a GET controller through query string I'd have to do:

```
curl -v -H 'ContentType: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://0.0.0.0:8848/my/test?param1[]=1&param1[]=2&param1[]=3'
```

isn't there a way to do something like:

```
curl -v -H 'ContentType: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://0.0.0.0:8848/my/test?param1[]=1,2,3'
```

without then having to split/manipulate the string to get the different values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the usual gem for sinatra: `https://github.com/mattt/sinatra-param`.

```
curl -v \
  -H 'ContentType: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  'http://0.0.0.0:8848/my/test?param1=1,2,3'
```

```rb
  get '/test' do
    param :param1, Array
  end
```

Comment: I need something more official unfortunately :(

Comment: Can't give much help to change the standard array param query, if gems are not allowed and having your own param processing is also not allowed.

Comment: gems are allowed, not personal ones though, only official ones.. but I understand what you are saying! Param processing is also to be left out to avoid mingling with string manipulation.. unless for "param processing" you mean something else